# Is it possible to connect to the local Windows shell with PuTTY?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, putty

I don't know of a working Windows SSH server (not one that I trust enough, yet, at any rate).

Therefore, I can't simply connect to `localhost` on port `22` from PuTTY.

I want to use PuTTY because the alternative (the old CMD program), used by all the consoles that I have installed (such as Git Bash and MSYS) doesn't make it easy to paste anything in. You have to right click and hit Paste. Screw that.

Does there exist a feature of PuTTY that hooks me directly to the windows shell?

Comment: search the webs for "puttycyg" -- I used that a while ago to use the putty terminal with a cygwin shell

Comment: I actually need to use PuTTY itself. I have a special fork of it I compiled. With hardcoded keybindings and stuff in it. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I can host my CLI programs on a Linux or a Mac, and use PuTTY with SSH.

I can do local stuff in CMD.EXE with these workarounds. http://www.techspot.com/guides/311-paste-cmd-using-ctrl-v/